# CodeIgniter Active Record multiple "where" and "or" statements

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following Active Record query.

```
//Example 1
public function info($school, $class, $student, $keyword)
{
    $this->db->where('school.id', $school);
    $this->db->where('class.id', $class);
    $this->db->where('student.id', $student);

    $this->db->or_where('school.description', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_where('class.description', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_where('student.description', $keyword); 

    return $this->db->get('info')->result();
}
```

I want to group the bottom 3 "or_where" statements so they are included with the top 3 "where" statements. The solution I came up with was this...

```
//Example 2
public function info($school, $class, $student, $keyword) 
{
    $this->db->where('school.description', $keyword);
    $this->db->where('school.id', $school);
    $this->db->where('class.id', $class);
    $this->db->where('student.id', $student);

    $this->db->or_where('class.description', $keyword);
    $this->db->where('school.id', $school);
    $this->db->where('class.id', $class);
    $this->db->where('student.id', $student);

    $this->db->or_where('student.description', $keyword); 
    $this->db->where('school.id', $school);
    $this->db->where('class.id', $class);
    $this->db->where('student.id', $student);

    return $this->db->get('info')->result();
}
```

This works fine, but is there a way to do this without repeating code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution!

```
public function info($school, $class, $student, $keyword)
{
    $this->db->where('school.id', $school);
    $this->db->where('class.id', $class);
    $this->db->where('student.id', $student);

    $this->db->where("(school.description LIKE '$keywords' OR class.description LIKE '$keywords' OR student.description LIKE '$keywords')");

    return $this->db->get('info')->result();
}
```

Comment: $keywords might be sql injection , need to escape first...
ex.  $this->db->escape_like_str($search)

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled into this and want to add following solution, which uses CI active record `$this->db->like()` syntax:

```
public function info($school, $class, $student, $keyword)
{

    $this->db->where('school.id', $school);
    $this->db->where('class.id', $class);
    $this->db->where('student.id', $student);

    $this->db->like('school.description', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('class.description', $keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('student.description', $keyword);

    return $this->db->get('info')->result();
}
```

Comment: The above does not group the LIKE conditions – and thus, it is not equal to the accepted solution by @Staysee. Unfortunately, the parenthesis (that tell MySQL to nest OR within AND) cannot be expressed in Active Record statements.